# How to add the test data from a variable in the report or a screenshot when using multiple-cucumber-html-reporter

Tags: testing, automated-tests, report, testcafe, cucumberjs

I am using [this](https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber) github project as a baseline to extend the capabilities in my existing testcafe project and to introduce BDD capabilities.

Also, I am trying [multiple-cucumber-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter) reporter to beautify end reports

I am using the Map object to generate runtime test data for each scenario and facing issues in posting the test data from map objects and screenshots in the report to show the test data and UI error used at each step or collectively.

I don't know how to achieve this and looking for some help in the right direction or working example would be a great help.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a test in which you are using the Map object to generate runtime test data for each scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The following shows cases of how to add data to the cucumber json report which I'm guessing your custom report pulls from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/attachments.md